# Cassandra - Removing a node from the cluster

Tags: cassandra

I have a cluster with three nodes and I need to remove one node. How can I make sure the data from the node to be removed will be replicated to the two other nodes before I actually remove it? Is this done using snapshots? How should I proceed?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

From the [doc](http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/operating/topo_changes.html#removing-nodes)

> You can take a node out of the cluster with `nodetool decommission` to a
>   live node, or `nodetool removenode` (to any other machine) to remove a
>   dead one. This will assign the ranges the old node was responsible for
>   to other nodes, and replicate the appropriate data there. If
>   decommission is used, the data will stream from the decommissioned
>   node. If removenode is used, the data will stream from the remaining
>   replicas.

Comment: Just for the update. removetoken is deprecated. Its removenode

Answer (score 11):

You want to run `nodetool decommission` on the node you want to remove. This will cause the node to stream all its data to the other nodes and then remove itself from the ring.